# How to unit test a UIViewController - TDD/BDD

Tags: ios, unit-testing, tdd, bdd, expecta

Unit testing is just something I never seem to be able to get my head around but I can see why its important and can be a huge time saver (if you know what you're doing). I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

I have the following `UIViewController`

**QBElectricityBaseVC.h**

```
@interface QBElectricityBaseVC : QBStateVC

@property (nonatomic, strong) QBElectricityUsage *electricityUsage;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat tabBarHeight;

- (void)updateElectricityUsage;

@end
```

**QBElectricityBaseVC.m**

```
@implementation QBElectricityBaseVC

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"electricity_title", nil) image:nil tag:0];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateElectricityUsage)
                                                 name:kUpdatedElectricityUsageKey object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.notificationCenter removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)updateElectricityUsage
{
    self.electricityUsage = [self.stateManager electricityUsage];
}

- (CGFloat)tabBarHeight
{
    return self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
}

@end
```

**What should I test?**

- An observer for `kUpdatedElectricityUsageKey` is added
- `self.electricityUsage` becomes an instance of `QBElectricityUsage`
- A `tabBarHeight` is returned
- An observer for `kUpdatedElectricityUsageKey` is removed

Am I missing anything I should test or testing something I really shouldn't?

**How do I test?**

So I am trying to do this using [Specta](https://github.com/specta/specta) and [Expexta](https://github.com/specta/expecta). If I need to mock anything I would be using [OCMockito](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito).

I really don't know how to test the observer is added/removed. I see the following in the Expexta documentation but not sure if its relevant/how to use it:

```
expect(^{ /* code */ }).to.notify(@"NotificationName"); passes if a given block of code generates an NSNotification named NotificationName.

expect(^{ /* code */ }).to.notify(notification); passes if a given block of code generates an NSNotification equal to the passed notification.
```

To test that `self.electricityUsage` becomes an instance of `QBElectricityUsage` I could create a category that has a method that just pretends the notification fired and calls the `updateElectricityUsage` method but is this the best way?

And as for the `tabBarHeight`, should I just test that it returns a valid `CGFloat` and not worry what the value is?

---

**UPDATE**

I changed my `viewWillAppear` method to look like below:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self addNotificationObservers];
}

- (void)addNotificationObservers
{
    [self.notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateElectricityUsage)
                                    name:kUpdatedElectricityUsageKey object:nil];
}
```

And then I created the following test:

```
#import "Specs.h"

#import "QBElectricityBaseVC.h"
#import "ElectricityConstants.h"

SpecBegin(QBElectricityBaseVCSpec)

    describe(@"QBElectricityBaseVC", ^{
        __block QBElectricityBaseVC *electricityBaseVC;
        __block NSNotificationCenter *mockNotificationCenter;

        beforeEach(^{
            electricityBaseVC = [QBElectricityBaseVC new];
            mockNotificationCenter = mock([NSNotificationCenter class]);
            electricityBaseVC.notificationCenter = mockNotificationCenter;
        });

        afterEach(^{
            electricityBaseVC = nil;
            mockNotificationCenter = nil;
        });

        it(@"should have a notification observer for updated electricity usage", ^{
            [electricityBaseVC addNotificationObservers];
            [verify(mockNotificationCenter) addObserver:electricityBaseVC selector:@selector(updateElectricityUsage)
                                               name:kUpdatedElectricityUsageKey object:nil];
        });
    });

SpecEnd
```

That test now passes but is this the correct/best way to test this?

Comment: I have the exact same questions - wish there were more documentation out there. Also, why didn't go with XCTest?

Answer (score 4):

You've just felt one big con of iOS ViewControllers: **they suck at testability**.

- ViewControllers mix logic of managing the view and model

  - This leads to massive ViewControllers
  - This violates the [Single Responsibility Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

    - This makes code not reusable

> Another big problem with MVC is that it discourages developers from
>   writing unit tests. Since view controllers mix view manipulation logic
>   with business logic, separating out those components for the sake of
>   unit testing becomes a herculean task. A task that many ignore in
>   favour of… just not testing anything.

[Article - source](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/model-view-viewmodel-for-ios/)

Maybe you should think about using MVVM instead. This is a great article explaining the difference of iOS MVC and MVVM.

The great thing about using MVVM is that you can use DataBinding using Reactive Cocoa. [Here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/74106/mvvm-tutorial-with-reactivecocoa-part-1) a tutorial that will explain Data Binding with MVVM and reactive programming in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I follow 2 practices for testing the pieces of a UIViewController.

1. MVVM - with an [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern you can very easily unit test the content of your views in your unit tests for your ViewModel classes. This also keeps your ViewController logic very light so you don't have to write as many UI tests to cover all of those scenarios.
2. KIF - then for UI testing I use [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) because its test actor helps handle async and view loading delays. With KIF I can post a notification from my code and my test will wait to see the effects of my notification handler in the view.

Between those 2 systems I'm able to unit-test pretty much everything and then very easily write the UI tests to cover the final parts.

Also, quick note on your code: I wouldn't add your observers in viewWillAppear because it is called more than once. However, it may not be an issue since you probably won't get redundant calls to your handler because of notification coalescing.